# How can my xbap program access a deployed file

Tags: wpf, xbap

I have a file called UserSettings.xml

When running inside VS I can access the file using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

How do I access the file when my xbap is deployed and is running in a browser?

The file is deployed under deep under %localappdata% but I don't know how to get the location.

Comment: What level of trust is the deployment in?

Comment: The app is deployed in Full trust

Comment: That's fine, can you check the sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970910.aspx where they show an xbap opening/saving a file?

Answer (score 0):

XBAP runs under severe restrictions, you can't access the fileSystem from an XBAP

Comment: Looks like he has already sorted out the restrictions via deploying it in full trust. What he is looking for is a way to navigate to the file path.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to call the following:

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`